# ¿Cómo insertar fecha en mysql con una columna tipo DATE usando PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de tabla de base de datos con 5 columnas: **ID, cliente, requerimiento, mensaje, fecha**. Las cuales son tipo: **int (auto incrementable), varchar, varchar, text, date** respectivamente.

Obtengo los valores de **cliente, requerimiento y mensaje** a través de un formulario html.

Si quisiera guardar únicamente *cliente, requerimiento y mensaje* haría esto. Ya que al guardarlo en la base de datos el ID va incrementando de 1 en 1.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO requerimientos (cliente, requerimiento, mensaje) VALUES ('$cliente', '$requerimiento', '$mensaje')";
```

¿Cómo podría guardar la fecha?

Comment: métela en tu insert o ponle un default en tu BD

Comment: Sé que se repite constantemente, pero sigue siendo cierto. Tu código tiene una vulnerabilidad seria de inyección SQL. Necesitas usar binding de parámetros para corregir eso.

Comment: Si la fecha es cuando se envía el formulario podrías utilizar la función **now()** de **MySQL** en la consulta, sería tan facil como añadir al `VALUES (now())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesita es guardar la fecha del sistema cuando hace el registro, pues sería:
$sql = "INSERT INTO requerimientos (cliente, requerimiento, mensaje, fecha) VALUES ('$cliente', '$requerimiento', '$mensaje', now())";

Comment: Gracias. Esto funcionó muy bien.